# How to access an Excel file from different PC

Tags: excel

I'm trying to access an excel file on some remote pc and make changes.

in the other machine, lets take the excel file name is `Sample.xls` and the machine ip address is `XX.XXX.XXX.XX`, on that machine when I enter `file:\\XX.XXX.XXX.XX/C$/Excel Files/Sample.xls` it is opening, When I'm trying to access the same file with the same address, it is throwing me the below error.

[image]

When I remove the `file` and give this URL `\\XX.XXX.XXX.XX\C$Excel Files\Sample.xls`. It is giving me the below error.

[image]

How can I access this file?

Comment: Can you simply try connecting to your remote machine and open the folder where your file is present just by passing the path till folder in run command prompt and see if you are able to open the folder?

Comment: one suggestion, try to map the remote location as network drive on your machine and see if it works.

Comment: The error message is fairly clear. You don't have permission to access that file in that way on that remote computer. You need to speak with whoever is responsible for administering that computer and managing security in your network.

Comment: @Siva, I'm unable to connect

Comment: @cyboashu, alroc. Do you guys say me to make that folder/ file in remote machine shared?

Comment: @user2423959, which mean either you don't have access to connect it or your path is wrong. Try mapping it as network drive as suggested by 'cyboashu'

Comment: Ohk, I'll try it and update you guys. Thanks for the help :)